# Checking Date Periods across a range of multiple accepted periods (eg Licensed Periods vs Use Periods)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Creating a check/DQ query that checks if the use of something was licensed during that time of use.

The Licensed record could overlap but is generally in a sequence but can also have gaps of time between licenses. This might sound a little bonkers but it's because the License could have categories that are at different times, but I'm ignoring that for the moment.

```
Licensed:       |------A-----------------||-C-|                     |-----E------|    |---F--|  |--G--|
                             |----------B----------||-D-|                                  |---H---|
Use:        xxxx1-||--2--| |-3-| |-4-| |--5--|    |-6-||-7xxx x8x xx9-|        |--x10x--|   |-11--|
```

Testing is the Use period exists completely in Licensed ranges.

- U1 - fails as it's only part of LA
- U2 - pass using LA
- U3 - pass using LA
- U4 - pass using LB OR LA
- U5 - pass using LB OR LA & LC
- U6 - pass using LB & LD
- U7 - fail part overlap of LD
- U8 - fail no overlaps
- U9 - fail part overlap of LE
- U10 - fail overlaps both LE & LF but not completely
- U11 - pass using LH

In my case it doesn't matter about returning which licenses it was accepted with, only that it was licensed during the use case, though it would be useful for debugging.

I'm not sure which angles to attack this from - while there are many Q's on comparing date periods, doing this all at the same time would be a time saver and in a simplified answer would be useful.

One assumption would be to simplify the L periods to summarised L ranges (using a CTE) first and then doing a not in range on the use cases? ie:

```
Licensed:       |------A---------------------------|             |-----B------|   |-------C------|
Use:        xxx-1-||--2--| |-3-| |-4-| |--5--|   |-6xxx xx7x  xx8-|        |--x9x--|   |-10--|
```

Although it will be more simplified in pre-filtering the Licenses that are covering the Use case. ie:

U2 will only look at A as the L date range only covers LA.

```
Licensed:       |------A-----------------|
Use:                 |--2--|
```

Hopefully, this is an interesting example that will occur as a real-life check on the fly in an application - so while I could use code to do this I'm hoping it'll be faster and more sensible/readable in SQL and I might turn it into a DQ report.

How would you do this? example.

Using SQL Server 2016 and/or VB.Net.

Example Data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #License
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Use

--License table
CREATE TABLE #License 
(
     ID char(1) NOT NULL, 
     FromDate date NOT NULL, 
     ToDate date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #License SELECT 'A', '2020-01-01','2020-03-01'
INSERT INTO #License SELECT 'B', '2020-02-01','2020-03-10'
INSERT INTO #License SELECT 'C', '2020-03-02','2020-03-05'
INSERT INTO #License SELECT 'D', '2020-03-11','2020-03-20'
INSERT INTO #License SELECT 'E', '2020-06-01','2020-07-01'
INSERT INTO #License SELECT 'F', '2020-08-01','2020-08-15'
INSERT INTO #License SELECT 'G', '2020-09-01','2020-09-15'
INSERT INTO #License SELECT 'H', '2020-08-10','2020-09-10'
--SELECT *, DATEDIFF(dd,FromDate,ToDate) AS Days FROM #License

--Use Cases
CREATE TABLE #Use 
(
     ID int NOT NULL, 
     FromDate date NOT NULL, 
     ToDate date NOT NULL, 
     ExpectedResult bit NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 1, '2019-12-01','2020-01-15', 0
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 2, '2020-01-16','2020-01-20', 1
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 3, '2020-01-20','2020-02-05', 1
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 4, '2020-02-10','2020-02-20', 1
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 5, '2020-03-01','2020-03-04', 1
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 6, '2020-03-08','2020-03-15', 1
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 7, '2020-03-18','2020-03-25', 0
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 8, '2020-04-01','2020-04-30', 0
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 9, '2020-05-20','2020-06-10', 0
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 10, '2020-06-10','2020-08-10', 0
INSERT INTO #Use SELECT 11, '2020-08-12','2020-09-08', 1
--SELECT *, DATEDIFF(dd,FromDate,ToDate) AS Days FROM #Use

-- Fails
--SELECT U.ID, ExpectedResult
--    , CASE WHEN L.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Result
--    , CASE WHEN ExpectedResult = (CASE WHEN L.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Success
--    ,*
--FROM #Use U
--LEFT JOIN #License L ON 
--    U.FromDate BETWEEN L.FromDate AND L.ToDate 
--    AND U.ToDate BETWEEN L.FromDate AND L.ToDate
----WHERE U.ID = 1
;
-- Using Gordons answer.
WITH lt AS (
    SELECT dateadd(day, 1, l.ToDate) AS test_date --, ID
    FROM #License l
)
SELECT Results.*, U.ExpectedResult, CASE WHEN U.ExpectedResult = Results.Result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ExpectedIsResult
FROM (
    SELECT u.ID --, *
    , COUNT(*) AS DateTests -- the amount of dates tested against licenses (USE and LICENSE To+1 within USE)
    , COUNT(l.ID) AS TestsMatchedLicense -- the amount that matched a LICENSE
    , (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(l.ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Result -- any date that didn't match that was required Fails the result.

    FROM #Use u CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT v.test_date
          FROM (values (u.FromDate), (u.ToDate) ) AS v(test_date)
          UNION ALL
          SELECT lt.test_date --Check the the U goes past a license
          FROM lt
          WHERE lt.test_date >= u.FromDate AND
                lt.test_date <= u.ToDate
         ) AS slt 
         --Match USE range dates to a LICENSE   AND   LICENSE TO+1 within USE range matches a LICENSE - as the LICENSE range may not cover the whole USE period but another license may.
         LEFT JOIN #License l ON slt.test_date BETWEEN l.FromDate AND l.ToDate 
    GROUP BY u.ID
) AS Results INNER JOIN #Use U ON Results.ID = U.ID
```

Using the simple attempt above gained a lot of success except for U6 - however not all the cases matched all the matched licenses either ie: U5

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as *text tables*.

Comment: Sorry, I'll build a sql example data and attempt - might be a while for the attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to test the start date, end date, and all license dates in between.  In particular, you care about 1 more than the end date -- the start of a potential non-license period.

```
with lt as (
      select l.*, dateadd(day, 1, l.todate) as test_date
      from license l
     )
select u.id,
       (case when count(*) = count(l.id) then 'Pass'
             else 'Fail'
        end)
from uset u cross apply
     (select v.test_date
      from (values (u.fromdate), (u.todate)
           ) v(test_date)
      union all
      select lt.test_date
      from lt
      where lt.fromdate >= u.fromdate and
            lt.todate <= u.todate
     ) lt left join
     license l
     on lt.test_date between l.fromdate and l.todate
group by u.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=edf7e46b7d71ad65415703e2bb1b04fe) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for this answer, having now tried it against the example and updating your answer with a couple of missed changes (which I've updated the script in the question), I'm struggling a bit on how it works - as it works as per expected. Can you go into a bit more on how all the segments of the query work perhaps. Otherwise gold star if you did this out of thin air.

Comment: Ok I think I understand -- you are matching all the USE range dates match a LICENSE range or if the LICENSE doesn't cover the whole USE range look for one next to the end of the LICENSE. Then match all the dates to test actually match LICENSE's ... certainly wouldn't have figured that out by myself.  Thank you.

Comment: @CooPzZ . .. You edited the question with sample data, so I edited the answer with a SQL Fiddle and your column names.

Comment: the example doesn't pass for U10.  I changed the 2nd select of the union to use the test_dates instead and it worked as expected. I'd also refrain from using 'lt' as the name of the CTE and the name of the joined dates  - this is what confused me in compiling the query, in my head, for a while as they weren't the same data.